# Cache-Control no affect in spring 4

Tags: xml, spring, cache-control

My application: Spring MVC 4.

I have set in my XML:

```
<mvc:resources mapping = "/resources/**" location = "/resources/" cache-     period="259201" />
```

I excepted that in my response will be set:my-age 259201. But nothing happened.

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Spring Security?

Spring Security will disable your caching headers.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#headers

```
<http>
    <!-- ... -->

    <headers defaults-disabled="true">
    <!-- <cache-control /> -->
    </headers>
</http>
```

If you want cache busting, look at using VersionResourceResolver.

Comment: Yes I use spring security 4.2.3.RELEASE. I have added above code to my security file. But nothing happened.  cache-period="259201" is ignored.
I use spring-mvc-cache-control artifact from maven repository dependency and add to My Controller annotation @CacheControl(maxAge = 259201) it works. But It is associated with controll but I want to use only cache-period="259201" to static resources.